# Asp.net core syntax how to create onclick event button to do a function

Tags: c#, asp.net

is it possible to help me to know how do I create an event when I click a button in asp.net core 3.1? I did a project in Blazor and it was easy to do that, I thought it was the same because it also uses razor pages .. I searched everywhere and I didn't find syntax .. I would like to change my site to asp.net core since it is better to create a database and add more features.
i use this code in blazor but dont work in asp.net core:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="calcular">Calcular</button>
@code{ private void calcular()
           {      
            ndias = (float)Convert.ToDecimal(cbdias);
            nfaltas = (float)Convert.ToDecimal(cdfaltas);
            horas = (float)Convert.ToDecimal(txthoras);
            bolsa = (ndias - nfaltas) * horas * 1.67;
            alimen = (ndias - nfaltas) * 4.77;
            transp = (float)Convert.ToDecimal(txttransp);
}
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: that link is only for syntax blazor not for the asp.net core that i want..

Comment: RazorPages isn't quite there yet with direct binding to c# code. You will still need to think in terms of the REST 'GET', 'POST', etc. methods. A good place to start is in the official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form), and each button will coincide with a server method of some sort. The razor syntax is useful for rendering, but Blazor goes a step further and brings in the c# interaction.

Comment: I already saw that, and try it but that is only to create database and sync each fields, not for what i want for click events for ex..